# equivalent of php's array_flip in flash actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, array-flip

Is there an equivalent of php's array_flip() in flash actionscript 3?   Here's the definition for array_flip:

`array_flip() returns an array in flip order, i.e. keys from trans become values and values from trans become keys.`

If not, what is the least verbose and most efficient way to achieve the same results as array_flip() in actionscript 3?

Comment: good question.  although i'm curious what situation would require inverting key/value pairs?

Comment: sometimes i have arrays like arr["en"]="English"; arr["fr"]="French";   Sometimes I know the key, and want the value, other times I know the value and want the key.  array_flip makes things easy like array_flip($arr)["English"] will give me the key.

Comment: ah ha!  so in this situation with AS3 you wouldn't necessirly need to invert the key/value pairs, you could just use some AS3 statements: answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function:

```
function flip(obj:Object):Object
{
    var base:Object = {};

    for(var i:String in obj)
    {
        base[obj[i]] = i;
    }

    return base;
}
```

Demo:

```
var array:Array = [];

array["a"] = "a1";
array["b"] = "b2";
array["c"] = "c3";

var newObj:Object = flip(array);

trace(newObj.b2); // b
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `for each...in` statement to [get the value](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for_each..in) associated to a key and use the `for...in` statement to [get the key](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for..in) associated to a value.